# Bash script works with all arguments except one

Tags: bash, macos, validation, command-line-arguments

I'm on OSX, and I need a bash script that handles multiple arguments. Based on some answers on this website, I wrote the following bash script (some strings have been removed for privacy):

```
#!/bin/bash

# A POSIX variable
OPTIND=1         # Reset in case getopts has been used previously in the shell.

# Default parameter value:
PORT=xxx
PUBKEY=xxx
HOST_IP=xxx

# show_help function
show_help() {
    echo "Usage: $(basename "$0") [-h] [-p PORT] [-f PUBKEY] [-i HOST_IP]"
    echo
    echo "   -p PORT           add key to container running on port PORT (default: xxx)"
    echo "   -f PUBKEY         add key file PUBKEY (default: xxx)"
    echo "   -i HOST_IP        connect to host HOST_IP (default: xxx)"
    echo
    return
}


while getopts ":h:p:f:i:" option; do
  case "$option" in
    \?)
      echo "invalid argument"
      show_help
      exit 1
      ;;
    h)
      show_help
      exit 0
      ;;
    p)  PORT=$OPTARG
      ;;
    f)  PUBKEY=$OPTARG
      ;;
    i)  HOST_IP=$OPTARG
      ;;
  esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))

USER_AT_HOST="root@$HOST_IP"
PUBKEYPATH="$HOME/.ssh/$PUBKEY"
ssh-copy-id -i "$PUBKEYPATH" "$USER_AT_HOST" -p "$PORT"

exit 0
```

the script works with all arguments (including an invalid argument), except for the argument `-h`. When I call the script as

```
script.sh -h
```

the result is the same as

```
script.sh
```

instead of showing me the help. Can you help me understand what's happening?

Comment: `echo invalid argument >&2; exit 1`. Do *not* show a usage statement in response to an error.  Print the error message to stderr and exit non-zero

Comment: But write a slightly more useful error message like `echo "illegal option -$OPTARG (-h for usage)" >&2`. It may seem helpful to print a usage statement, but it really isn't.  Go to a directory that is not managed by git and type `git diff`. You will probably  (depending on the version) see an irrelevant message telling you about such useful options as `--ext-diff` and `--color-moved-ws` and `--skip-to`, but the useful information that you are not in a git repo has scrolled off the top of the terminal.  Keep the error message succinct, relevant, and accurate.  Don't give wall of text.

Comment: @WilliamPursell ok, basically you're suggesting that I remove the call to `show_help` after `echo "invalid argument"`. Will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:` after `h` in `getopts ":h:p:f:i:"` means that `-h` requires an argument, but I don't think `-h` needs any arguments. Remove the colon after `h`.

Normally, getopts would display an error:

```
option requires an argument -- h
```

But, as you started the string with another colon, error reporting was turned off. Remove the initial `:` to see the errors in argument processing.

Answer (score 1):

In the `getopts` pattern `h:` says that `-h` must have an argument (eg, `-h 2`) so, have you tried `script.sh -h 2`?

If `-h` should not have any args then remove the `:` after the `h` leaving you with `getopts ":hp:f:i:"`